# Finding the determinant of the adjoint of matrix of A whose determinant is 2.

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

**Question**

Let $A$ be a 4 x 4 matrix with determinant 2. Recall that we can write $A^{-1}=\frac{1}{\det A} \text{adj} A$. Find the determinant of the adjoint matrix of A.

$$\color{yellow}{--------------------------------}$$

**What I did:**

$$\det(A^{-1})=\det\left(\frac12 \text{adj} A\right)$$

$$\det(A^{-1})=\frac1{2^4}\det\left( \text{adj} A\right)$$

$$\frac12=\frac1{2^4}\det\left( \text{adj} A\right)$$

$$\det\left( \text{adj} A\right)=2^3$$

$$\color{gold}{\Large{\text{Am I correct?}}}$$

Comment: It is right and it is a general formula: if $\;A\;$ is a square *regular* matrix of order $\;n\;$ , then $$\det(Adj\,A)=\left(\det A\right)^{n-1}$$

Comment: @Timbuc oh i never knew this. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you're correct. ${}{} {}{}$ ${}$